# printing from snow leopard to zebra lp 2844 from html page

Tags: label, osx-snow-leopard, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

i am attempting to print labels from our custom CMS for products using EPL2 label printer drivers but having no luck.

the printer spits out about 12 labels (4x1") but no text is visible.

i set up the printer manually and using the CUPS admin interface and get the same results each time.

zebra doesn't make a native driver, but i am finding on the web that this driver should work.

any advice would be much appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of data are you sending to the device? If you're just doing a File->Print of the web page it should work with the OS drivers, no need to go into the CUPS interface. If you're writing to the spool folder you should be sending raw EPL code - look for the EPL Programming Guide @ Zebra.com

Make sure you setup the device correctly as well.
http://www.nrgsoft.com/blog/?p=11

Comment: thanks for the reply. that is actually the page i went to before i set it up. i followed the directions exactly and still get the same problem. i may try to call Zebra.

Comment: Zebra will be of little help as they don't offer Mac support. When you add the device manually and print from a web page you don't get any output other than blank labels? Could it be that you don't have the correct direct thermal label stock? Check this link for more info... http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/resource_library/faqs/thermal.html

Answer (score 0):

what ended up working was doing a factory reset and using @page along with paper size settings to print in the correct dimensions.

the only printer i could get to actually work the way it was supposed to was Chrome.